# Spark RDD double compare error: value > is not a member of (Double, Double)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

i want in pairthree, (a,(b,c)) only filter c>100

```
pairthree.take(3)
```

res8: Array[(Double, (Double, Double))] = Array((44966.0,(6.5,2.0)), (5015.0,(879.0,248.0)), (47202.0,(32.0,8.0)))

```
val pairhundred =pairthree.filter { case(k, v) => v > 100.0 }.take(3)
```

command-173749889538375:2: error: value > is not a member of (Double, Double)
val pairhundred =pairthree.filter { case(k, v) => v > 100.0 }.take(3)

I dont understand why this error is happened ...

Comment: ```v``` is of type tuple, you need to use either ```v._1 > 100.0``` or ```v._2 > 100.0```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v` is of type `Tuple`. Try Below code.

To check `first` parameter `> 100` in tuple

```
val pairhundred =pairthree.filter { case(k, v) => v._1 > 100.0 }.take(3)
```

To check `second` parameter `> 100` in tuple

```
val pairhundred =pairthree.filter { case(k, v) => v._2 > 100.0 }.take(3)
```

To check `both` parameters `> 100` in tuple

```
val pairhundred =pairthree.filter { case(k, v) => (v._1 > 100.0 || v._2 > 100.0) }.take(3)
```